# Blade template - @extends & @section not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm learning the laravel framework and trying to get to grips with using the blade template engine. However i cant for life of me get the @extends and @section functionality to work within my project.

I have already tried reinstalling the whole project multiple times, using different browsers and restarting my machine but i cant figure out why it doesn't display the @section content

Laravel Version: 5.7.28 | 
IDE: PhpStorm

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts/index');
});
```

views/layouts/index.blade.php

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Site Index</h1>
    @yield('header')
</div>
</body>
```

views/header.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.index')

@section('header')
    <p>Header</p>
@endsection
```

At the moment all that is being displayed is the  tag in the views/layouts/index.blade.php file.

Thank you very much for any and all input on this.

Comment: are you sure that in your route loading view is working?

Comment: @D.Khumoyun im pretty sure because the h1 tag is being displayed on the view, just not the content being extended in.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how the templating works. You have to reference the child template in your return statement. Because the `@extends` is in this child template, Laravel knows to use the mentioned master layout. So your return statement would be like so:

```
return view('header');
```

If you just want the header to be displayed on every page, you don't need to extend the master layout in your header, you should just include the header part in your master layout.

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Site Index</h1>
    @include('header')
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tested the view and layout they seems working. check your controller return statement. try `return view('header')`;

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('header');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your responses, now i understand how the blade template engine works a little better and how i was doing this wrong. Just for clarification for others that get confused like me and come across this thread:

When you are redirecting to a view through the web routes then it has to be a child that is extending from a layouts master.

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

The html from the master file will then be displayed by default and its the content that we are "viewing"

views/layouts/master.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>@yield('title', 'default title if unspecified')</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Master Header</h1>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

To work with the content of the page then its the index view that is worked with using the @section('content') method.

views/index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Changing the default title')

@section('content')
    <p>content displayed</p>
@endsection
```

I hope this helps for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to show content of section('header') then you must return header view like

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('header');
});

this is because contents are in header view and you have been extending layout.index

so if you return layout.index view you will not see content of section('header')
```